# Grease fill does not respect linewidth

Tags: grease-pencil

I have a grid consisting of grease lines and some circles with grease as well:

[image]

I can fill these circles with the same color, however these fills does not have any thickness - the lines do and so they overlap:

[image]

As you can see, the fill goes under the grid lines/stroke. It's because the fill value does not seem to have any "depth"

This is evident if I disable the strokes on the circle. You can see the grids linewidth has some depth.

How can I give the fill the same depth?

[image]

Comment: Here is an example scene, where two circles stroke is above some lines, but their fill is under: https://we.tl/t-at6BiJkL9O

Comment: To easily replicate:
Make a new 2d-grease scene. Make two overlapping circles. Give them both a different fill-color and stroke-color. 

You will see the fill-color does not overlap, but the stroke does overlap.

Comment: WeTransfer link is expired. You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ to share the .blend file. You should include the link you get there in the body of the question.